# Joomla! & VirtueMart - show product category instead of shop front?

Tags: joomla, categories, virtuemart

I have a Joomla! 1.5.15 and VirtueMart 1.1.4 installation from a client project and I need to change something I'm not sure how to.

I have one of my menu links pointing to the shop (menu item type: VirtueMart) but it directs me to a front page (to be precise, it renders the content in `themes/default/templates/common/categoryChildlist.tpl.php`).

What I want is for this link to make one of my product categories show.

I've tried several methods (without any luck so far):

- Using `header()` doesn't work (I know, it's a pretty shameful trick, but I had to try it).
- Changing the menu item type doesn't work (you can't modify the link itself).
- Modifying any of the `browser_` files doesn't work either (at least, doesn't look like it).

I'm a bit out of ideas... any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I used VM 1.1.x, but isn't there a Category menu item available in the menu manager? (by the way you are way out of date I think 1.1 got to version 1.1.9 before it reached EOL).

I would also strongly recommend updating your Joomla! installation to at least 1.5.26 with the additional hotfix that was released recently (Joomla 1.5.x is also EOL).

Comment: No, we can't update the software versions. They're already working on a production server and both my boss and our client don't want any change at all in that direction.

Comment: I found the solution. I changed the menu item type from `VirtueMart` to `external URL` and I could attach the shop category URL directly into the menu. Your category hint has been gold for me. Thanks a lot! :)